# Mouse sharing for Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, mouse, clipboard, multiple-workstations

I recently found [Mouse without Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460) but this just works for Windows.

My question is now if there is something like that which works with Ubuntu with a secure connection.
It should provide

- Mouse sharing
- keyboard sharing
- Clipboard sharing
- secure (encrypt data)

If possible for free.
I would appreciate OpenSource

Comment: This post is one of the ones that showed up when I was googling for the same thing so figured I'd give a more recent answer for future souls: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/setup-barrier-share-mouse-keyboard-between-computers/ worked great for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is an app out there called Synergy.  I'm just discovering this, so I know nothing about it.  I just stumbled across this article: 
http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/share-mouse-and-keyboard-with-your-windows-linux-machines-with-synergy-1-7-1

Comment: According to their website (https://symless.com/synergy where I was taken by links from the above answer), the download what is used in the answer is not free - am I right?  (The page has tabs of which one says "buy").  Why not using synergy that was incorporated in the free default repos of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible for free, out-of-the-box in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install synergy
```

This software comes from the Ubuntu repositories and is free, open source and has all the needed (at least for me) properties (at least for 14.04 LTE).

---

And to complete the answer:

This command is better to use when installing, because it does not let you install stuff unless you have your repos up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synergy
```

and this gives you a clue on what is available in the repos you have configured on your machine:

```
apt-cache search synergy
```

As long as 16.04 LTE, standard repos are considered:

```
quicksynergy - GUI for easy configuration of Synergy
synergy - Share mouse, keyboard and clipboard over the network
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this. I have the same need right now. But I need to share mouse between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. I downloaded Synergy on Windows and found it's not free. Am I missing anything? Or is it only free for Ubuntu?

Comment: (please upvote the answer if helpful) https://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy-stable-builds/  free windows version available -- the official website won't tell you ;)  but there is a sourceforge version, although 3 years old (so use cautiously).  I don't mind using it and I succeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with Barrier-KVM. This works perfectly for me. You can also use this with different subnets and different OS Platforms.